# Atmospheric Entry Simulation: Numerical Inaccuracy

Tags: orbital-mechanics, aerobraking, simulation, entry-descent-landing, analysis

I am trying to make an atmospheric entry/aero-assist simulation. For the propagator, I have used conventional equations of motions in planet fixed reference frame:

[image: Equations of Motion]

where the scalar states are- longitude( $\theta\ $), latitude ( $\phi\ $), radial distance(*r*), Velocity (*V*) Horizontal Flight Path Angle( $\gamma\ $) and vehicle heading angle ( $\psi\ $).

[Reference: Optimal trajectories for the Aeroassisted Flight Experiment. Part 1: Equations of motion in an Earth-fixed system](http://hdl.handle.net/2060/19900004125)

In that, if I were to neglect aerodynamic terms (L,D,Q) and obtain propagated states, they should comply with extra-atmospheric flight/ two body orbit.

The result is decent to look at in the inertial frame but I see an Angular momentum and orbital specific energy variation of cyclic nature with variation in magnitude shown below. (for r = 4396.19, v=2.80963)

[image: Angular Momentum and Energy]

That's 54 $ \ km^2/s \ $ (min to max) in about 4000 seconds. If I were to make sense of this for a constant radial distance, it comes up to be a velocity addition of 0.012 km/s. Matter is worse for high elliptical orbit.

I double checked the equations used in the solver and the transformation between frames.

So my questions are:

1. Can this be due to numerical approximation in MATLAB? Why is the variation so ordered?

I understand that the equations contain terms that are 'large' and then some that are comparatively smaller in orders of magnitude. Can this be a plausible reason behind such a variation?

If that is the case, what solution do I have, other than deriving canonical state variables and re-writing the differential equations?

2. Apart from validation, I would use this propagator for an aero-assist scenario, where I would just need it for atmospheric flight regime. Is the error acceptable?
   If so, The error would cause states to diverge (which I've observed for longer time intervals). If I were to use this, what maximum time interval should I consider executing this solver?

Comment: If you're seeing something varying periodically over an orbit that should be constant, then there are more likely causes of the problem than your numerical propagator.

What are you using for g?

Comment: @djr I have tried using g as $ \mu /r^2  $ with f=0 as well as f and g as components with J2 coefficient augmented

Comment: OK, I would expect that should be fine. Other things I would try in debugging would be to see if I can get the result I expect for a circular equatorial orbit, and to see if I can get the result I expect if I set the rotation of the Earth to 0.

Comment: @djr You were right. I did test polar and equatorial with all conic section orbit cases, with no difference. But, setting rotation rate to 0, brings down error to expected levels.

Comment: @djr $ \omega $ terms is in coupled acceleration terms as well as in Planet Inertial <-> fixed transformation matrix. What should I be looking for in these fairly standard expressions?

Comment: Another thought, which is consistent with what you've found so far: have you definitely calculated angular momentum and orbital energy correctly? (Specifically, have you allowed for the fact that V is corotating?)

Comment: @djr Right! I have treated velocity vector like a length vector and transformed from one frame to other without considering corotation component. So, I eliminated the transformations and derived velocity vector from time difference rate of inertial position, which solves the problem. I'll also try to derive velocity from scalar velocity through transformations.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that you've solved the problem, and I hope that my suggestions were helpful.